# Chart.js | Multiple data-set line chart with arrows

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to use a line chart in Chart.js to achieve the below result. I cannot see anywhere in the Chart.js documentation where you can customise the lines.

If anyone has an idea on how I can achieve this, that would be very helpful!

[image: Graph showing goal result]

Comment: Can't do this with basic Chart.js, you either need to create your own custom chart type or you can use the annotation plugin

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.